# Salesforce: Create a Trigger to insert record in custom object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I'm trying to insert a new record into my custom object Commission_C. There are no errors in the code, but nothing happens when Policy_C is updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
trigger statusUpdate on Policy__c (before update) 
{
    List<Commission__c> comms = new List<Commission__c>();

    for(Policy__c a : trigger.new)
    {
       Commission__c comm = new Commission__c ();
       comm.Name = 'testName'; 
       comms.add(comm);      
    }

    insert comms; 

}
```

I've googled extensively, and from what I can tell, this seems to be what it should be. I've simplified my code because essentially I just need this part to work to get it all working.

Comment: Weird. Is the trigger definitely saved OK in the target environment? (be it sandbox or production org?) Is it marked as active? What if you'll for example force it to fail (`System.assert(false, 'Die you stupid trigger!');` should work)? Do you know how to enable debug logging and thus trace what happens when you update Policy?

Comment: This is what happened when I put a debug after the insert. I'm really new to this, so I don't know much about how to debug with salesforce/apex.

10:52:53:184 USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|(Commission__c:{Name=testName, Id=a01i000000B2RIFAA3})

Comment: Oh, and the trigger itself is fine, because I was able to get it to send an email on update. This part does nothing though.

Comment: If commission got Id assigned it means it was saved successfully. You should be able to navigate to it by using the id value in an url (say `https://eu1.salesforce.com/a01i000000B2RIFAA3`). Maybe you expect to see it on a related list or something? But you don't specify any relationship like `comms.Policy__c = a.Id;`...

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger statusUpdate on Policy__c (before update) 
{
    List<Commission__c> comms = new List<Commission__c>();

    for(Policy__c a : trigger.new)
    {
       Commission__c comm = new Commission__c ();
       comm.id=a.id
       comm.Name = 'testName'; 

       comms.add(comm);      
    }

    insert comms; 

}
```

Comment: Maybe you could describe using a little more detail how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need check if you missed any required field of Comission__c, and also check if the security setting is set right.  Turn on debug log, you should be able to see what went to wrong.

Answer (score 0):

trigger statusUpdate on Policy__c (After update) 
{
    List comms = new List();

```
for(Policy__c a : trigger.new)
{
   Commission__c comm = new Commission__c ();
   comm.Policy__c = a.id;
   comm.Name =a. 'testName'; 
   comms.add(comm);      
}

insert comms;
```

}

Now You can try this Trigger i think all most it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

trigger statusUpdate on Policy__c (after Insert) 
{
    List comms = new List();

```
Commission__c comm = new Commission__c ();

for(Policy__c a : trigger.new)
{
   comm.id=a.id;
   comm.Name = 'testName'; 
   comms.add(comm);      
}

insert comms;
```

}